# What would be the effect of increasing the number of bytes?

Tags: byte, pixel

One byte is used to store each of the three color channels in a pixel. This gives 256 different levels each of red, green and blue. What would be the effect of increasing the number of bytes per channel to 2 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

2^16 = 65536 values per channel.

Comment: and this would be better, yes?

Comment: define better. you get more of a color range, but it is twice as large... depends on what you are doing. Also if your data is already only 8bpp then extending that won't increase the quality or anything.

Answer (score 0):

The raw image size doubles.

Processing the file takes roughly 2 times more time ("roughly", because you have more data, but then again this new data size may be better suited for your CPU and/or memory alignment than the previous sections of 3 bytes -- "3" is an awkward data size for CPUs).

Displaying the image on a typical screen may take more time (where "a typical screen" is 24- or 32-bit and would as yet not have hardware acceleration for this particular job).

Chances are you cannot use the original data format to store the image back into. (Currently, TIFF is the only file format I know that routinely uses 16 bits/channel. There may be more. Can yours?)

The image quality may degrade. (If you *add* bytes you cannot set them to a sensible value. If 3 bytes of 0xFF signified 'white' in your original image, what would be the comparable 16-bit value? 0xFFFF, or 0xFF00? Why? (For either choice-- and remember, you have to make a similar choice for black.))

Common library routines may stop working correctly. Only the very best libraries are data size-ignorant (and they'd still need to be rewritten to make use of this new size.)

---

If this is a real world scenario -- say, I just finished writing a fully antialiased graphics 2D library, and then my boss offhandedly adds this "requirement" -- it'd have a particular graphic effect on *me* as well.